# Strange behaviour when compiling auctex from MELPA inside Cygwin's Emacs (w32 version)

Tags: emacs, auctex

I tried to compile the auctex from Emacs MELPA. The version is: 11.88.4

When I first open a .tex file, compile AUCTEX, and change to "TeX-latex-mode", Emacs will work properly, the menu bar also change to latex state.

However, when I close Emacs, restart Emacs again and open a .tex file, Emacs will give:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Autoloading failed to define function TeX-latex-mode")
```

And auctex will not work...

It seems the problem is in autoloading certain state when initialize the auctex for a tex file.

Any help?

Comment: Try just `LaTeX-mode`… AUCTeX should have 'advised' it to run its functionality.

Comment: I do not quite understand. I didn't specific a "TeX-latex-mode". It is because I was in Tex-mode before I installed auctex. If I open new file after the auctex installed, emacs will give the error.

Comment: I assume you tried restarting Emacs?

Comment: Yes. If not restarting, changing to Latex-mode will work. If restarting, it give the error...

Comment: Without more information about your configuration, it will be impossible to help. If it's of any use to you, feel free to use [my configuration](https://github.com/vermiculus/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el#L260-273).

Comment: @SeanAllred I tried to reduce the configurations to minimum and still do not work... Here is my configuration: http://pastebin.com/9H7VMd7M

Comment: Can you tell us how you've installed emacs and *what* configuration you're running? Does it work at all with `emacs -q` (following all the standard package initialization procedures manually)?

Comment: I installed from cygwin setup program. Configuration is above. It do not work even start Emacs with "emacs -q".

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved! My mistake.

I modularised my init.el and separated the LaTeX settings to latex.el, which conflict with the `latex.el` in auctex.

I renamed the file to latex_settings and everyting works fine. (A small warning that no docstring for 'tex-start-shell', but that's fine.)

Comment: Yep, that'd be a problem :) I'm glad everything worked out.